# Evaluate how many 4 digit numbers can be formed > using at least one of these letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Below are given 4 digit passwords using symbols $M,N,1,0,8,9$
>
> $$\boxed{N}\boxed{N}\boxed{1}\boxed{1} \cdot
>  \boxed{0}\boxed{9}\boxed{N}\boxed{M}\cdot 
>  \boxed{N}\boxed{N}\boxed{N}\boxed{N}$$
>
> How many ways can you choose an ordered 4−tuple of these characters given that repetitions are allowed and given that at least one of M,N must be used?

I've no idea concerning what this question actually means. Could you assist me?

Regards

Comment: I assume it means "how many ways can you choose an ordered $4-$tuple of these characters given that repetitions are allowed and given that at least one of $M,N$ must be used."

Comment: @lulu You are very right.

Comment: Any comments? Please share it with me.

Comment: Your question was "what this question actually means".  I answered that.  To solve it, count the unrestricted $4-$ tuples and then count the $4-$ tuples that use only numbers, and subtract.

Comment: @lulu Could you please provide an example?

Comment: The question already provides three examples. Please study my hint (which is close to a full solution) and try to do it on your own.

Comment: @lulu That's what my goal is, but I'm still unable to interpret what you mean by that.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with it?

Comment: lulu's suggestion is 1)  Answer how many 4 tuples can be made from these six characters including M and N.  2) how many 4 tuples can be made from the four characters that exclude M and N.  and 3) subtract the answer to 2, from the answer to 1.  You should not need any hints on how to answer 1 or 2.

Comment: Those are all the hints for now.  We will give you more hints if you show some effort on answering 1) or 2) on your own.  You *should* be able to solve it and there aren't very more hints to give.  In fact, I can't think of any hints to give. ... Okay, heres a hint.  List all the two character strings you can make.  And count them.  There are less than 100 of them so just list them all: 00, 01, 08, 09, 0M, 0N, 10, 11, ... etc., count them, and tell us how we could have *known* without counting how many there were.

Comment: You have a choice of $6$ symbols for each of $4$ boxes. So unrestricted, there are $6^4$ password possibilities. Given that one of these boxes has to contain at least an M or an N, how many do we subtract from $6^4$ which don't contain an M or N to get the answer? Hint: you have only $4$ symbols to distribute to the $4$ boxes.